# How to remove lists with certain words from a list of lists or list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples, strip

1. List of Lists
   [['b'],['d'],['e'], ['b','d','e'],['b','e'],['e','f'],['b','d']]
2. List of tuples
   [('b',),('d',),('e'),('b','d','e'),('b','e'),('e','f'),('b','d')]

I would like to remove any lists or tuples that contains both the characters 'b' and 'd'. So the output should look like below.

remove lists = [['b','d']]
remove tuples = [('b','d')]

Modified List of Lists
[['b'],['d'],['e'], ['b','e'],['e','f']]

Modified List of tuples
[('b',),('d',),('e'),('b','e'),('e','f')]

Preferrably i would like to do this for more than one combination of lists/tuples say remove lists = [[e,f],[b,d]] to remove any lists that contain characters e and f as well as b and d.

I highly appreciate any help that can be provided.

Comment: What language it is?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. It's in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple list comprehension will suffice. Works for both list of lists and list of tuples.

```
abc = [['b'],['d'],['e'], ['b','d','e'],['b','e'],['e','f'],['b','d']]

# Characters to remove
rm = [['e','f'],['b','d']]

# Function takes two list of lists as input
def refine_list(mylist, stuff_to_remove):
    for to_remove in stuff_to_remove:
        mylist = [x for x in mylist if not set(to_remove).issubset(set(x))]
    return mylist

print(refine_list(abc, rm))
```

Output:

```
[['b'], ['d'], ['e'], ['b', 'e']]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Is there a way to do the same thing to remove multiple lists at the same time using list comprehension. Like rm = [['b'],[',b','d']] to remove multiple combintaion of characters at once.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer. Please note that both inputs to the function are list of lists.

Comment: Not sure if the code is update yet. If I run with rm = [['b'],['b','d']] it throws TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: There should a function called `refine_list()`.

Answer (score 1):

I made for you an easy to read and understand code snippet that use an helper function to remove list of strings/chars/letters from either list of lists or list of tuples

please comment if you have any question, if you done know what the enumerate method does, look it up online. let me know if you manage to understand the solution

```
def remove_chars(lists, list_of_chars):
    result = []
    for idx, list in enumerate(lists):
        if all(letter in list for letter in list_of_chars):
            pass
        else:
            result.append(list)
    return result


list_of_lists = [['b'],['d'],['e'], ['b','d','e'],['b','e'],['e','f'],['b','d']]
list_of_tuples = [('b',), ('d',), ('e'), ('b', 'd', 'e'), ('b', 'e'), ('e', 'f'), ('b', 'd')]
letters_to_remove = ['b']

filtered_lists = remove_chars(list_of_lists, letters_to_remove)
print(filtered_lists)

filtered_tuples = remove_chars(list_of_tuples, letters_to_remove)
print(filtered_tuples)
```

```
# remove list of list of chars:
list_of_list_of_letters = [['b'],['b','d']]

for list_of_letters in list_of_list_of_letters:
    filtered_lists = remove_chars(list_of_lists, list_of_letters)
    print(filtered_lists)

    filtered_tuples = remove_chars(list_of_tuples, list_of_letters)
    print(filtered_tuples)
```

Comment: Thank You so much. I will test this one out :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks again. This code works for the specified example. However, if I change letters to remove [b, d] to just [b] the code returns some lists with character b in it. Not sure, where’s the bug.

Comment: @VigneshRamasamy hey, I fixed the code, the problem was that if two consecutive lists/tuples had 'b' the popping of the index will 'skip' over the next real index and second list including 'b' would not be filtered out.  In order to solve it I just define a new result list and added any list that do not contain any of the letters

Comment: Great! I see what you have done now. It works!

Comment: Is it possible to add more than one list to letter_to_remove? For instance, if I want to remove multiple lists say both ['b'] and ['b','d'] this script maynot work right with current logic?

Comment: for sure ! just create the list of list of letters and for each list of letters call the function we created, I all add that code for the answer itself, please accept the answer as correct if helped you :) thanks

Comment: I just tested the above updated code with the list for loop and it looks like it doesn't work. It still output [['b'], ['d'], ['e'], ['b', 'e'], ['e', 'f']]. It does work when you switch the lists inside the list_of_list_of_letters = [['b','d'],['b']].